# LED Shoes - circuit diagram ok?

Tags: led, diy

I want to put LEDs into my shoes, specifically the Nike Air bubble (by drilling holes at the inside of the shoe and dropping them into the bubble).  I also want the ability for it to light up when dancing. I was thinking a Force Sensitive Resistor at the heel. 
Im hoping to use a high mAh rechargeable battery too, for usability. But they tend to have a 8.4V rated voltage. Will that work?

[image]

Ive tried simplifying the layout. Ive added in AAs instead of the 9V to allow for longer mAh. Removed the mini controller. And switched the LEDs to 3V's. Will i need resistors if both the battery and LEDs are 3V? The FSR is rated up to 22lbs, so anything over 22lbs should provide max current? The rechargable AAs are rated at 1.2Vs, will this still power the LEDs?
[image: circuit 2]

Comment: How do you plan on reinflating them once you've pierced the bubble?

Comment: Link is dead...

Comment: Try it out outside before mounting it. What you will see at best is a dimming of the lights. Isn't the most efficient option.

Comment: A resistor near each LED is missing

Comment: @digitalism Please post one question, this is a Q & A style forum and there is one question and one answer. Editing is for clarifying the question. This is a forum to ask circuit design questions, not for projects.

Answer (score 4):

Will it work? Sort of. You're on the right track.

The issue is the force sensitive resistor (FSR) will probably not go low enough in resistance to have the LED's light up visibly unless you really smash down on it *every time* Also you will want to have the FSR wired in series with one of the +9v wires like you have it, *before* the controller.

The solution is have the FSR drive some kind of circuit which can effectively take the "signal" from FSR and use *that* to switch the power on and off. An easy way would simply be to have the FSR drive a transistor.